# How do I setup multiple price tier In App Purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, appstore-approval

I got trouble with submitting my app on Apple store 
I'm implementing an education app that contain various packages in different content and I want to set multiple price for each one. However after coding and setup as introduction guide my app was rejected by Apple and the reason wasn't specific. Does anyone know about this case? Please advise me if you went through.

[image]

[implement steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlmVL.png)

Comment: what do you mean by " I want to set multiple price for each one"?

Comment: you must be read apple guide line for in-app purchase then after goto next step.. https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I meant I'd like to select price tier 1 to 5 because our packages may have different price due to content provider. Is that Apple does not allow to sellect multiple price like this?
Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

As i know, each products must have one price, i think that's your problem.

Comment: Yes I submitted separately package price and it's fixed price. Is that Apple only accept one price tier for our case?
Thanks for your advise!!